# Remove the discontinuity of $f(x) = \frac{x^2-11x+28}{x-7}$ at $f(7)$?

Tags: calculus, continuity

I need to remove the discontinuity of $f(x) = \frac{x^2-11x+28}{x-7}$ at $f(7)$, and find out what $f(7)$ equals. I am not sure what I've done wrong, but I'm getting 33, which the website I'm using tells me is wrong.

Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

**My Steps:**

$$\frac{x^2-11x+28}{x-7} \cdot \frac{x+7}{x+7}$$

$$=\frac{x^3+7x^2-11x^2-77x+28x+196}{x^2-49}$$

$$=\frac{x^3-4x^2-49x+196}{x^2-49}$$

$$=\frac{x^2(x-4)-49(x+4)}{x^2-49}$$

$$=(x-4)(x+4)$$

plug in $7$ for $x$.

$$(7-4)(7+4)=7^2-16=33$$

Comment: No, that's not the right way.  Instead of multiplying top and bottom by $x+7$, you will need to divide the numerator by $x-7$.  Synthetic division will give you the quotient.

Comment: You should factor the numerator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain why you get the wrong answer, in your second last line, the last term of the numerator is $-49(x-4)$ and not $-49(x+4).$

Faster approach:

$$\frac{x^2-11x+28}{x-7}=\frac{(x-7)(x-4)}{x-7}=x-4$$

Hence to remove the discontinuity at $7$, the right value to redefine at $f(7)$ should be $7-4$.

Factorization should be the way to go, multiplying by the conjugate doesn't serve the purpose here.

Answer (score 2):

x=7 is a root of $x^2-11x+28$. So write $x^2-11x+28=(x-7)p(x)$. Then $f(7)=p(7)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x^2-11x+28=(x-7)(x-4)$. Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to remove it at $7$ and not at $f(7)$. Write $$ f(x) = {(x-7)(x-4)\over x-7 } = x-4$$

So $$\lim_{x\to 7} f(x) =3$$